# Enabling unicast response(PTR and SRV) in apple's mDNSResponder code

Tags: mdns

I'm using apple's mDNSResponder(mDNSResponder-320.10.80) code for my service discovery stuff which is working fine for me with multicast but now my requirement is changed and i need to make it to work for unicast.  I read the internet draft, in that they have specified like enabling unicast response bit we can get the unicast response.  I have tried by doing that also but its not working.  Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This option may help , I have not tried ..
you can try the option as embedded client and set the flag kDNSQClass_UnicastResponse = 0x8000

and try ,